# How can I define a function called "import" in Python?

Tags: python, function, import, command-line-interface, python-click

Im writing a small python commandline tool which can import some data.

Usage looks like

```
./cli.py export -p
./cli.py import -p
```

Obviously, "import" conflicts with the normal import statment. So the function looks like

```
@click.command(short_help="Imports all documents",
@click.option('password', '-p')
def import(password):    
    coll = db.get_document_collection()
```

Since im using `click` library for parsing/building my commandline options, each function gets imported with its name. But when i execute it, it fails.

```
   def import(password):
            ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

TLDR; How can I specify a function that is already defined by python internals?

Comment: You could change the case of any 1 character like **def Import():**.

Comment: Why does it have to be called `import`?

Comment: You could use `def import_(password):`.  The real question is, why does it need to be `import`?  You might use `import_password`.  It isn't a good idea to work around that.  There's a very good reason for not overwriting keywords, so it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the function without changing `click`'s options would indeed rename your subcommand. However, click lets you use any function name you'd like, and provide the subcommand name you want to associate with it.

For example, this will give you the subcommand `import` which will run the function `my_import_func`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command('import')
def my_import_func():
    click.echo("Importing")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Redefining built-in names is a bad idea.